# Where's the conflict here?

Tags: templates, overloading, d

Why can't I overload this template function?

```
import std.stdio;

T[] find(T, E)(T[] haystack, E needle)
    if (is(typeof(haystack[0] != needle)))
{
    while(haystack.length > 0 && haystack[0] != needle) {
        haystack = haystack[1 .. $];
    }
    return haystack;
}

// main.d(14): Error: function main.find conflicts with template main.find(T,E) if (is(typeof(haystack[0] != needle))) at main.d(5)
double[] find(double[] haystack, string needle) { return haystack; }

int main(string[] argv)
{
    double[] a = [1,2.0,3];
    writeln(find(a, 2.0));
    writeln(find(a, "2"));
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell, the two functions can't accept the same argument types.

Comment: I don't think the language lets you overload *any* template function..

Comment: @Mehrdad: You can overload. In particular std.algorithm.find is overloaded several times.

Comment: @PeterAlexander: Wait really? Every time I've tried to make a regular function 'overload' a templated one, I've gotten an error....

Comment: @Mehrdad: Ah, yeah, you can't overload a template function with a non-template function, but I think that's a DMD bug. Not sure.

Comment: I wrote this code while reading chapter 5 of TDPL, which clearly implies you could overload a template of find() with `int[] find(int[] longer, int[] shorter)` and in case the arguments are compatible with the plain function, the compiler should use the plain function even if the template function can also accept the arguments.

Comment: @Qwerties: There's a few things TDPL says that aren't implemented yet. Here's the current list: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=%5Btdpl%5D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't overload template functions with non-template functions [due to a bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1528). This should hopefully be fixed sometime in the future.

In the meantime, you can write the other function as a template specialisation:

```
T find(T : double[], E : string)(T haystack, E needle)
{
    return haystack;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. On the upside, bugs are being resolved rapidly http://dlang.org/bugstats.php

Comment: Sometimes all you have to do is add a set of empty parens, ala:
double[] find()(double[] haystack, string needle) { return haystack; }

Not sure if it would work in this case, but it can be a workaround for bug 1528.